# Spark Streaming writeStream is not writing to file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

writeStream seems to be working if my output format is "console", but not when my output format is "parquet". Is there some additional set up or configuration that I'm missing?

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

object DataStreaming extends App with Context {

  val customSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("x", DoubleType),
    StructField("y", DoubleType),
    StructField("name", StringType)
  ))

  def readFromParquet(): Unit = {

    val sourceDF: DataFrame = spark.readStream
      .schema(customSchema)
      .parquet("/path/to/source/")
    
    sourceDF
      .writeStream
      .format("console")
      .outputMode("append")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()

    sourceDF
      .writeStream
      .format("parquet")
      .option("path", "/output/path/")
      .outputMode("append")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
  }

  readFromParquet()




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird. All I have to do was comment out

```scala
//    sourceDF
//      .writeStream
//      .format("console")
//      .outputMode("append")
//      .start()
//      .awaitTermination()
```

and also update

```scala
    sourceDF
      .writeStream
      .format("parquet")
      .option("path", "SOMEPATH")
      .option("checkpointLocation", "SOMEPATH")
      .outputMode("append")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
```

and it worked fine.

Comment: when I try this its gives value writeStream is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ReceiverInputDStream[String]